# alter the structure Tastypie uses in the list view

Tags: django, tastypie

I have json list view that look like this:

```
{
"objects": [
{
  "active": false,
  "id": 4,
},
{
  "active": false,
  "id": 5,
}
]
}
```

I want to get rid of "objects" word, so that structure will look like this:

```
{
[
{
  "active": false,
  "id": 4,
},
{
  "active": false,
  "id": 5,
}
]
}
```

This [link to docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/paginator.html#implementing-your-own-paginator) has no clue in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible. `{}` means `dict`. Dict needs key and value.

I guess You need

```
[
  {
    "active": false,
    "id": 4,
  },
  {
    "active": false,
    "id": 5,
  }
]
```

If yes, overwrite `Resource.alter_list_data_to_serialize` function:

```
def alter_list_data_to_serialize(self, request, data):
    return data[self._meta.collection_name]
```

Paginator class need to be dict with field named `Resouce._meta.collection_name`.

Comment: You are right! That's what I need! But now I get this error `{
  "error_message": "",
  "traceback": ..... raise TypeError\n\nTypeError\n"
}

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I fixed the answer.